# codeigniter INSERT only inserting variable names

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

i've lost a good few hours on this and i'm sure it's something quite simple!

I'm quite new to codeigniter.

Basically i want to perform a simple INSERT into my database using values recieved from my form here is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Page Title</title>

   </head>
   <body>

<div id="formage">

    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('../add_client'); ?>
    <p>
    <?php echo form_label('First Name', 'first_name');?>
    <?php echo form_input('first_name', '', 'id="first_name"' );?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <?php echo form_label('Last Name', 'second_name');?>
    <?php echo form_input('second_name', '', 'id="second_name"' );?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <?php echo form_label('Email Address', 'email_address');?>
    <?php echo form_input('email_address', '', 'id="email_address"' );?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <?php echo form_label('Password', 'password');?>
    <?php echo form_password('password', '', 'id="password"' );?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <?php echo form_label('Confirm Password', 'passwordconf');?>
    <?php echo form_password('passwordconf', '', 'id="passwordconf"' );?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Add New Client');?>
    </p>


    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div>
```

This calls my controller:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Add_client extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function index(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_name', 'Second Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length(4)');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordconf', 'Password', 'required|matches[password]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() !== false){
        $this->load->model('add_client_model');
        $this->add_client_model->addUser(
        $this->input->post('first_name'),
        $this->input->post('second_name'),
        $this->input->post('email_address'),
        $this->input->post('password'));

    }



    $this->load->view('add_client_view');

}


 }
```

Which in turn calls the addUser function from my model:

```
<?php

  class Add_client_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct(){
}

public function addUser($fname, $sname, $email, $password){

        $this->db->set('first_name', $fname);
        $this->db->set('second_name', $sname); 
        $this->db->set('email_address', $email); 
        $this->db->set('pasword', sha1($name)); 
        $this->db->insert('users');
}
 }
```

The problem i am having is that whenever i submit my form and the function is called it seems to insert the variable name like so (see second row):

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/76853467/Picture%204.png

I cant seem to get it to accept the post data i plug into my function parameters!

Any suggestions?  Much thanks!

Comment: I know this is a way to do it but have you tried: $this->db->insert('users', array('first_name' => $fname,'second_name' => $sname,'email_address', => $email, 'password' => sha1($name))); Maybe there's a bug with set method. Btw there is an error in the password field set. password is with 2 S'sses in your table.

Comment: Thanks for help, i have amended the wrong spelling and inserted the array but still no luck. could it be something to do with the way the function is called?

Comment: add to the __construct function in the model: `parent::__construct();`

Comment: Tried all suggestions and still nothing. Also now that i've made some adjustments, when i call the function in my controller $this->add_client_model->add_user();  i am getting a blank page and any echo's/print_r's i call are not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$data = array(
  'first_name' => $fname,
  'second_name' => $sname,
  'email_address' => $email,
  'password' => sha1($password)
);

$this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately still returning variable names instead of value.

Comment: For debug add"

print_r($data); exit; 
after $data variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... I have had sporadic issues sometimes too, but seems on in CI 2...

However, how about using the good old $_POST object to access it? this is after all where CI will get it's data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the variable values using echo or using firephp (if you're using it) ?

Ensure that the parameters send the appropriate value to the model as it accepts from the post.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the form helper in your controller. Perhaps you already autoloaded it though? If not, try adding it in there.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```